# datas not showing in tables when change occurs, angular

Tags: html, angular

I've got a problem that is linked to my `*ngIf`. I've got two buttons displaying different data in the same table. I'm filtering an array of object. The problem is that if I click on one of this button like "Dog" the correct data is displayed but after if I click on "cat" the columns will be empty. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong ?

animal.ts

```
  cat: boolean;
  dog: boolean;

  animals: Animal[] = [
    {type: 'cat', name: 'snoopy', color: 'white'},
    {type: 'dog', name: 'spooch', color: 'black'}
  ];

chooseCat() {
    this.cat = true;
    this.dog = false;

    this.animals = this.animals.filter(d => {
      return d.type === 'cat'
    });
}

chooseDog() {
    this.cat = false;
    this.dog = true;

    this.animals = this.animals.filter(d => {
      return d.type === 'dog'
    });
}
```

animal.html

```
 <div class="col-xs-12" class="icon" (click)="chooseCat()">
      <img src="../assets/img/cat.png" class="icon;">
      cat
 </div>

 <div class="col-xs-12" class="icon" (click)="chooseDog()">
      <img src="../assets/img/dog.png" class="icon;">
      dog
 </div>


<table *ngIf="cat || dog">
<tr>
<td>name</td>
<td>color</td>
</tr>

<tr *ngFor="let a of animals">
<td>{{a.name}}</td>
<td>{{a.color}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: When you select dog the filtered data only contains dogs, so there is no cat inside `animals` array. Moreover, you need to make your `animals` readonly and you should use a temporary variable. Or you can just use a `pipe` for filter it.

Comment: Your filtering by checking the `name` property but you meant to check the `type` property.

Comment: You have one typio and one logic error. As Typio filter attribute is wrong as login you shouldn't filter same array again and again your core data should be same you need to produce filter array from core array .One solution is second array another one is pipe. In answer I detailed both examples you can check it @yorozuya

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dcrewc?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

your filter condition is wrong change to type and  create one more array and assing it in html

```
 this.animals2 = this.animals.filter(d => {
      return d.type == 'cat'
    });
```

in html like

```
<tr *ngFor="let a of animals2">
<td>{{a.name}}</td>
<td>{{a.color}}</td>
</tr>
```

or another solution is custom [pipe](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mgkryp?file=src/app/app.component.html)

add custom pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any[], args: string): any {
    console.log(value)
    return value.filter(x=>x.type==args);
  }

}
```

create `typee` as parameter in component

```
typee:string;
```

in html change `typee`

```
 <div class="col-xs-12" class="icon" (click)="typee='cat'">
      <img src="../assets/img/cat.png" class="icon;">
      cat
 </div>

 <div class="col-xs-12" class="icon" (click)="typee='dog'">
      <img src="../assets/img/dog.png" class="icon;">
      dog
 </div>
```

then assign custom pipe to table

```
<tr *ngFor="let a of animals | filter : typee">
  <td>{{a.name}}</td>
  <td>{{a.color}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click on 'Cats' and filter the first time you exclude all dogs from the 'this.animals' array. When you then click on 'Dogs' you filter all cats from the *same* array thus emptying it completely. If you want to display all the dogs or cats you should rather do a deepCopy of your original array and not filtering it.

Comment: This is basically correct although I don't think a deep copy is desirable here. Also this isn't an answer

Answer (score 0):

You are filtering on 'name' in your methods. That should be 'type'.

Try this:

```
chooseCat() {
  this.cat = true;
  this.dog = false;
  this.animals = this.animals.filter(d => {
    return d.type === 'cat'
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've changed the condition but it's still not working. I can display one list but if I click on the other button to display the second list it returns empty